# Pine script - get value from another indicator with input.source

Tags: pine-script

I try to get some values from another indicator with the input function and the type of input.source. When I use only one input function, I can select the other variable. When I use more input functions, I don´t get a selection of the other values.
Some ideas?

VPSV indicator must be in the chart

```
var float previousDevPOC = 0.0
var float previousDevVAhigh = 0.0
var float previousDevVAlow = 0.0

devPOC := input(title="Dev. POC", type=input.source, defval=close)
devVAhigh := input(title="Dev. VA high", type=input.source, defval=close)
devVAlow := input(title="Dev. VA low", type=input.source, defval=close)
```

Comment: There are only one source input allowed in the script.